# Speed up numpy array concatenate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have following code. I convert cp_X_train from RGB to grayscale and concatenate it with X_train_gray.

```
X_train_gray = np.empty([0, 32, 32, 1])

start = timer()
for i in range(cp_X_train.shape[0]):
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(i)
        end = timer()
        print(end - start)
        start = timer()
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(cp_X_train[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)[None, :, :, None]
    X_train_gray = np.concatenate((X_train_gray, gray_img), axis=0)
```

I print out the processing time every 1000 sample.

```
0
0.00042258699977537617
1000
3.331055953000032
2000
9.222047281000414
3000
15.596254615000362
4000
21.37355997799932
5000
27.513121935999152
6000
33.477182841001195
7000
40.4089376539996
8000
47.39131554400046
9000
53.73745651799982
```

As you can see, at the start, processing time is small. But as X_train_gray grows larger, the processing times get bigger. How do I fix this situation?

Comment: Could you not concatenate to a list your gray_img's and then call `np.concatenate` at the end? Currently you're growing the array iteratively which is non-performant

Comment: You could also create X_train_gray as an array of zeros and then overwrite them with `X_train_gray[i] = ...`. If you have to know the number of images beforehand.

Comment: `numpy.concatenate` has to allocate memory for a new array and then copy the data from the two given arrays every time. So, you're constantly re-building a growing array, which takes a lot of memory and time.

Comment: @EdChum: I know I am growing the X_train_gray iteratively. But I don't know how to fix this. I have to store every gray_img.

Comment: declare an empty list outside your loop, append to this your gray imgs in the loop. After your loop call `np.concatenate` once passing your list of gray_imgs

Comment: I got it, thank you.